# Airflow docker-compose up executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am working on dockerrising an Airflow based python project.

The DockerFile is below

```
# BASE IMAGE
FROM 524881529748.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hotels-ecs-base:python3.6

ENV APAXY http://apaxy.mmt.com/

RUN yum-config-manager --add-repo http://bizeye.mmt.com/SOFT/nexus.repo && yum-config-manager --disable \* && yum-config-manager --enable Nexus3

RUN yum remove -y mysql-community-server-minimal
RUN yum install -y gcc
RUN yum install -y mysql-devel

# INSTALL ANACONDA
RUN yum install -y wget
RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/anaconda.sh
RUN /bin/bash ~/anaconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda
RUN yes | rm ~/anaconda.sh

# ACTIVATE CONDA & INSTALL REQUIREMENTS
COPY docker-requirements.txt docker-requirements.sh /tmp/
RUN sh /tmp/docker-requirements.sh

USER airflow
```

The image is build successfully using

```
docker build . -f Dockerfile --pull --tag hotels-ecs-base:python3.6
```

When I run the containers using
`docker-compose up`

I get the following error

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "version": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

The docker-compose.yaml is (got from airflow)

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.3/docker-compose.yaml

I am new to docker. Could anyone suggest something?

`Edited`

Full Output of docker-compose up

```
[+] Running 6/6
 ⠿ Container airflow-compose-postgres-1           Running                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 ⠿ Container airflow-compose-redis-1              Running                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 ⠿ Container airflow-compose-airflow-worker-1     Recreated                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 ⠿ Container airflow-compose-airflow-webserver-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 ⠿ Container airflow-compose-airflow-scheduler-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 ⠿ Container airflow-compose-flower-1             Recreated                                                                                                                                                0.1s
Attaching to airflow-compose-airflow-init-1, airflow-compose-airflow-scheduler-1, airflow-compose-airflow-webserver-1, airflow-compose-airflow-worker-1, airflow-compose-flower-1, airflow-compose-postgres-1, airflow-compose-redis-1
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "celery": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Comment: what are the exact steps that you follow? You say you build the image but then you run docker-compose. That's not really how it should work. Also where does the image you build fit into the docker-compose.yml you mention?

Comment: @Mihai I am using the same build image into the docker-compose.yml

image: hotels-ecs-base:python3.6.

I am using this 
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#quick-start-scenarios-of-image-extending

Comment: then you should not have to build separately. Just declare it in docker-compose.yml. You should post the full output from docker-compose up to understand which container exactly is failing

Comment: Edited the question with full error output.
I am installing some requirements using the Dockerfile.